# I have a div with scrollbars. How can I detect if someone mousedowns on the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with scrollbars. How can I detect if someone mousedowns on the scrollbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the jQuery scroll function `.scroll()` and pass it a function to be called when scrolling occurs. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) for more info.

Example:

```
$('#targetdiv').scroll(function(event) {
  //Stuff to do when scrolled
});
```

You then might be able to use the event data to see if a mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.7 you can use `$('#targetdiv').on('scroll', callback);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onscroll) event.  jQuery also has a [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) convenience function.

I'm not sure if you can detect the scroll direction.

Comment: you can't get the scroll direction from the event, but you can store the location, and compare the current to last to determine if the scroll is up or down...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can.  But I believe you can bind something to the `scroll` event of the div that will trigger when the div actually has it's content's scroll position changed.